# for_each for aws_iam_policy data block - not working (dynamic code inside loop)

Tags: foreach, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform 0.14

Here is a working version of my code:

```
#MODULE DEFINITION (in a folder named "iam-group-with-policies")

resource "aws_iam_policy" "custom" {
  count = length(var.custom_group_policies)

  name        = var.custom_group_policies[count.index]["name"]
  policy      = var.custom_group_policies[count.index]["policy"]
  description = lookup(var.custom_group_policies[count.index], "description", null)

  tags = var.tags
}

#RESOURCE DEFINITION

module "iam_group_with_custom_policies_S3" {
  source   = "../modules/iam-group-with-policies"
  name     = "S3_viewer"

  group_users = ["user8", "user9"]

  custom_group_policies = [
    {
      name   = "Custom_S3viewer"
      policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sample.json
    },
  ]
}

#DATA BLOCK

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sample" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:ListBuckets",
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

using that data block defined above is mentioned here - https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-iam-policy?in=terraform/aws#refactor-your-policy

It is working perfectly fine, I can have multiple resource definitions pointing to different data blocks.

Now I wanted to extend this code to add more variables to it to support multiple policy creation using single block of resource, so I thought of using for_each:

```
#MODULE DEFINITION

resource "aws_iam_policy" "custom" {
  count = length(var.custom_group_policies)

  name        = var.custom_group_policies[count.index]["name"]
  policy      = var.custom_group_policies[count.index]["policy"]
  description = lookup(var.custom_group_policies[count.index], "description", null)

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "this" {
  count = var.create_group ? 1 : 0

  name = var.name
}

resource "aws_iam_group_membership" "this" {
  count = length(var.group_users) > 0 ? 1 : 0

  group = local.group_name
  name  = var.name
  users = var.group_users
}

################################
# IAM group policy attachements
################################

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "custom_arns" {
  count = length(var.custom_group_policy_arns)

  group      = local.group_name
  policy_arn = element(var.custom_group_policy_arns, count.index)
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "custom" {
  count = length(var.custom_group_policies)

  group      = local.group_name
  policy_arn = element(aws_iam_policy.custom.*.arn, count.index)
}




#RESOURCE DEFINITION

module "iam_group_with_custom_policies_looptest" {
  source   = "../modules/iam-group-with-policies"
  for_each = var.user_groups
  name     = each.key

  group_users = each.value.user_list

  custom_group_policies = [
    {
      name   = each.value.policy_name
      policy = each.value.policy
#     policy = lookup(var.user_groups_policies, each.key, [""])
#     policy = {trim(each.value.policy, "\"")}
    },
  ]
}

#VARIABLE DEFINITION

variable "user_groups" {
  description = "Map of user groups and associated custom policies"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    EB_viewer = {
      policy_name = "Custom_EB"
      user_list = ["user7", "user9"]
      policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.custom_eb.json
    },
    EC2_viewer = {
      policy_name = "Custom_EC2viewer"
      user_list = ["user8", "user9"]
      policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.custom_ec2viewer.json
    }
  }
}

#DATA BLOCK

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "custom_ec2viewer" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:DescribeFastLaunchImages",
      "ec2:DescribeInstances"
      "ec2:DescribeConversionTasks"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "custom_eb" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "elasticbeanstalk:DescribePlatformVersion",
      "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeAccountAttributes",
      "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

but this is failing with following error:

```
Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON policy

  on ../modules/iam-group-with-policies/main.tf line 45, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "custom":
  45:   policy      = var.custom_group_policies[count.index]["policy"]



Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON policy

  on ../modules/iam-group-with-policies/main.tf line 45, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "custom":
  45:   policy      = var.custom_group_policies[count.index]["policy"]
```

I feel the problem is with the line in RESOURCE BLOCK where I mention:

```
  policy = each.value.policy
```

here it is considering the literal string that will come out as a value of "each.value.policy" i.e. "data.aws_iam_policy_document.custom_eb.json" OR "data.aws_iam_policy_document.custom_ec2viewer.json". but I want it to execute this and get the value that resides in that data block.

To all the terraform gods out there, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is `var.user_groups`?

Comment: var.user_groups refer to a variable called "user_groups", whose definition is mentioned there in question

Comment: Its not possible to make a variable refer to any other variable or a data source in `var.user_groups`. Please clarify what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I don't want to have multiple resource definitions pointing to different data blocks to define a user group and policy associated with it.

Comment: Your `variable "user_groups"` is incorrect. Its not possible to get the error you are reporting here, with `variable "user_groups"` definition that you showed in the question.

Comment: It is working fine, even if I remove "user_groups.default[*].policy" from vars and put "policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.custom_eb.json" in resource definition, it still works. the problem would be it will create two different user groups with two different policies attached to it with the same permissions as bothh policies will inherit actions from "data.aws_iam_policy_document.custom_eb.json"

Comment: My point is that `variable "user_groups"` in your question can't be the real one that you use. This makes your question and code not reproducible.

Comment: Its real, you just have to make sure user7, user8, user9 exists ...

Comment: I have added other part of the modules in the question